# How to make maven plugin get properties from the pom file, the project that uses it?

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

I am writing a maven plugin. I need the following functionality. So that my plugin can read properties from the properties section of the project file that my plugin will use. Is it real?

[image]

Primary goal:
The data that is needed for my plugin to work can be passed through the <-Configuration-> section, but I need the ability to pass parameters through the command line when calling my plugin.
Unfortunately, the same parameter will be specified in both the <-configuration-> section and on the command line, then the maven, in priority, will take values from the <-configuration-> set.
I need that, even if the value is specified in the <-configuration-> section, it will return the value that will be passed on the command line.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Comment: First will you really read properties which usually does not make sense; It's usually better to have a configuration where you can use of course properties? Maybe you can give more background so we understand what kind of problem you are trying to solve...